# How can I compute tangents for loaded geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I'm writing a custom shader using RawShaderMaterial and I want to access tangents as an attribute in the vertex shader.

Is this possible using regular geometry or do I need to use bufferGeometry? I'm using REVISION 80, (currently the dev branch). I don't think there is a way to access attributes other than position, uv, normal and color when using regular geometry.

If I go with bufferGeometry, I am unable to use THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.computeTangents because it requires the index property which is always null after converting geometry to bufferGeometry using the fromGeometry method (bufferGeometry.fromGeometry(geometry)) or after loading bufferGeometry (THREE.BufferGeometryLoader).

Is there a way to compute the index array from the vertices array after which I would be able to run THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.computeTangents?

I don't want to have to resort to computing tangents in the shader.

Comment: There is index setting in [THREE.BufferGeometry.fromGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/BufferGeometry.js) code (line 490). However, you could make fresh bufferGeometry and addAttributes / setIndex manually (using existing geometry attributes / index).

Comment: http://www.cs.upc.edu/~virtual/G/1.%20Teoria/06.%20Textures/Tangent%20Space%20Calculation.pdf

Comment: @mlkn I think that might be my best bet, or something similar. I'm thinking now that I will compute tangents on the regular geometry first and then convert that to bufferGeometry adding the necessary attributes, including tangents at that time.

Comment: @pailhead Thanks for the link. I've got code that will compute my tangents. I am more concerned with how to get them into my shader as attributes.

Comment: what is your concern? Either index them, or do a triangle soup, you need one tangent per vertex, the same with normals

Comment: you can definitely use Geometry for computing since you have much more information and structure, but making an attribute out of it should be trivial